# NUXT 3: ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prismic')

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I work on prismic and I would like to use slice machine preview on nuxt 3.

I get this error after downloading yarn add nuxt-sm vue-slicezone @nuxtjs/prismic @prismicio/slice-simulator-vue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWpCC.png)

I work on prismic and I would like to use slice machine preview on nuxt 3.

I get this error after downloading yarn add nuxt-sm vue-slicezone @nuxtjs/prismic @prismicio/slice-simulator-vue.

Comment: This most likely looks like a compatibility with Nuxt 3. Did you check if the prismic module is compatible with the latest version ? If so, it's probably under another tag.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@nook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8886385/nook) , `@nuxt/prismic` doesn't have a released version that supports vue 3

however, you can try their RC version by

```bash
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/prismic@rc
```

also check out
https://v3.prismic.nuxtjs.org/